# Let $A = \{1, 2\}$. How many subsets $X$ of $S$ are there so that $XRA$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Define a relation $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(S)$ by: for any $X,Y \in \mathcal{P}(S)$, $XRY$ if and only if $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$.  Let $A = \{1, 2\}$.  How many subsets $X$ of $S$ are there so that $XRA$?

I understand the problem, but have trouble counting the set, which contain $1$ or $2$ and also may or may not contain any element from S.

My solution:

1. Choose $1$ or $2$ to be in the set, $2$ ways to do that
2. Choose any element from $S$ to be in the set, $2^8$ ways to do that

Final answer is: $2 \cdot 2^8 = 2^9$, and $2^9$ is the total number of subset of S, which is not correct.

So how do you make sure $1$ or $2$ are in the set as well as any number of elements from S?

Comment: You could use [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Actually it is done in the second part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to count the number of subsets $X$ such that $X\cap A=\varnothing$ and then subtract this from the total number of subsets, which gives $2^9-2^7=3(2^7)=384$.

---

We can also do this by counting the number of subsets containing 1, which is $2^8$ (since we can select any subset of $\{2,\cdots,9\}$ to also include with 1), adding the number of subsets which contain 2, which is also $2^8$, and then subtracting the number of subsets containing both 1 and 2, which is $2^7$.

This gives an answer of $2(2^8)-2^7=2^9-2^7=384$.

Comment: did you mean to say {1,...,9} instead of {2,...,9}?, Oh and so if you want to find out then number of subsets which do contain some element for example 1 in this case, you would do 2^8.

Comment: And if S = {1,2,3,4,5}, and I want to know how many subsets of S will contain 1, I would do 2^4?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.